# Content encoding = utf-8 problem while testing a web application using jmeter

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, test-strategy

I’m new to `Jmeter` and I'm currently testing a `web application` using `Jmeter`. When I’m trying to record using `HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder`, `Jmeter` records 'two' `HTTP Request` for 'one' static screen (I'm not performing any other functionality on screen). Also, when I tried to investigate I came to know, that the only difference is, in second `HTTP Request`, `Content encoding = utf-8`.
When I ran this `Test Plan`, I noticed that in `View Result Tree`, under Request tab, value of `Accept` and `Referer` fields are getting changed.

My query: Is this application sending request twice for each screen? Or am I missing something? Or is this behavior the intended behavior?

Example: Below is sample output form from a static screen named `Image Gallery-First` on `View Results Tree`:

1. `Request Headers:`
2. `Connection: keep-alive`
3. `Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5`
4. `Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8`
5. `User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0`
6. `Referer: http://Applicationname.com/`
7. `DNT: 1`
8. `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate`
9. `Host: (Application-name).com`

Second outcome on `View Results Tree`:

1. `Request Headers:`
2. `Connection: keep-alive`
3. `Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5`
4. `Accept: image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5`
5. `User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0`
6. `Referer: http://applicationname.com/tof.AN.UI/Product/IdeaImageGallery`
7. `DNT: 1`
8. `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate`
9. `Host: Applicationname.com`

Please help me understand this and kindly excuse me if my question is very basic.

**Note:**

I tried to research for content encoding and I found this on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17154967/is-content-encoding-being-set-to-utf-8-invalid

Answer (score 3):

The second request is image which is somewhere at the page you're hitting with the first request. I believe that it should be expected for image gallery to have some images.

I would recommend to delete the second request from recorded samples and use [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) configured to `Retrieve all embedded resources` and use pool of 3-5 threads for it as this is what real browsers do.

See [How to make JMeter behave more like a real browser](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/115022-how-to-make-jmeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) guide for another piece of advice on how to make your test more realistic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Dmitri. I have already added the components mentioned in the link. Also, I have added the HTTP Request Defaults. I just wanted to confirm that, Can I delete the second request. Thank you, your answer was helpful!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a network analyser / packet sniffer such as [Fiddler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiddler_(software)) to get a trace of a browser's normal http/https requests, and compare with what JMeter has been recording?

Answer (score 0):

@Dmitri T hit the nail on the head, but I wanted to walk you through a little about how you could deduce the origin of the request. Looking at the headers you posted, you can clearly see more differences than just the content-encoding. The following lines also differ in important ways:

> Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Vs

> Accept: image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5

and

> Referer: http://Applicationname.com/

vs

> Referer: http://applicationname.com/tof.AN.UI/Product/IdeaImageGallery

To debug this, you'll want to look at the page being hit. Where is something referring to IdealImageGallery? By the accept header, it's looking for a .png file at that location. By your description of the page as an image gallery, you can tell that it is probably looking for an image in the gallery.